# NodeJs async/await again

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I just can't get my head around this stuff :(

```
    compatibleApps: async () => {
        common.header('Install Compatible Apps')
        const compatibleApps = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/compatibleApps.json', 'utf8'));
        const value = await inquirer.compatibleApps();

        for (let element of value.removeAppsList) {
            for (let element2 of compatibleApps) {
                if (element === element2.name) {
                    await files.downloadFile(element2)
                }
            }
        }

        await adb.installApk()
    },
```

await adb.installApk() is being executed before the all calls of await files.downloadFile(element2 ) have been completed..

Below is the contents of downloadFile, I guess I need to wrap it in a promise?

```
downloadFile: async (element) => {
    option = {
      dir: './data/apps',
      onDone: (info)=>{
          console.log('Latest ' + element.name + ' Downloaded')
      },
      onError: (err) => {
          console.log('error', err);
      },
      onProgress: (curr, total) => {
      },
  }

  var dd = await dl(element.url, option);
  }
```

Comment: What does files.downloadFile return? Have you confirmed it is a promise?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `await` only does anything useful if you are awaiting a promise that is linked to your actual asynchronous operation.  "Linked" in that sentence means that the promise resolves when the asynchronous operation is done or rejected if it has an error.

If the function you are awaiting either returns nothing or returns just a plain value, yet contains asynchronous operations, then the `await` doesn't actually `await` anything.  It calls the function, initiates those asynchronous operations, the function returns a non-promise value or returns an already resolved promise, the `await` doesn't have a anything to wait for and just continues executing more lines of code without the expected pause for the asynchronous operations to complete.

So, in your code, the only way that:

```
 await adb.installApk()
```

executes before any of the calls to:

```
await files.downloadFile(element2)
```

is if `files.downloadFile()` does not actually return a promise that is linked to the asynchronous operations it contains or perhaps if you never execute `files.downloadFile(element2)` because of the conditionals.

For more specific help, show us the code for `files.downloadFile()` and confirm that you are getting through your conditionals and executing it at least once.